# Jailing particular users on login

Tags: chroot

This whole deal with jails and chroot is a bit confusing to me. They are used to run possibly risky programs securely, but this has to be initiated by the user. I'm looking for how to jail users like how Android and iOS do it. This can be setup for remote logins, but how can this be set for home logins?

Assume that I have Ubuntu installed on a desktop PC. There are four users: administrator, user1, user2, and guest. The first logs in like an account normally does. The second and third login to a jail. The fourth logs into a more restrictive jail than the second and third. Do these jailed accounts have access to a virtualized environment of sorts? Do these include copies of core binaries or are they built into the all's interface? Are these accomplished with initialization scripts or something else?

Answer (score 4):

Chroot jail setup

Create user to be jailed.

```
$sudo adduser acer
```

For setting chroot we need to set sudo privilage to the users.

Add the user in sudo group

```
    $sudo adduser acer sudo
```

Create folder to setup a user in jail

```
    $sudo mkdir /chroot
```

The jail user can access only whatever inside the /chroot folder

This means we need to provide something in there,unless the user only can see empty folder

Just create basic necessary things

```
    $cd /chroot

    $ sudo mkdir bin dev etc home lib usr var

    $sudo mkdir etc/pam.d home/acer lib/security var/log usr/bin
```

We want to copy the software to /chroot that the jail user can able to use

Bash command

```
    $which bash 
    /bin/bash
    $sudo cp /bin/bash /chroot/bin
    $ldd /bin/bash
    #This ldd command is used to list the library function  
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb772d000)
            libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0xb76f0000)
            libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb76eb000)
            libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb753c000)
            /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb772e000)

Copy this lib file to chroot lib directory

$sudo cp  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 /chroot/lib
    $sudo cp /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 /chroot/lib
    $sudo cp /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /chroot/lib
    $sudo cp /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /chroot/lib
```

ls command

```
$which ls
    /bin/ls
    $sudo cp /bin/ls /chroot/bin
    $ldd /bin/ls
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb771f000)
            libselinux.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0xb76e1000)
            libacl.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1 (0xb76d8000)
            libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb7529000)
            libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xb74eb000)
            libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb74e6000)
            /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7720000)
            libattr.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1 (0xb74e0000)
```

Copy this lib file to chroot lib directory

```
    $sudo cp /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 /chroot/lib
    $sudo cp /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1  /chroot/lib
    $sudo cp  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /chroot/lib
    $sudo cp  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 /chroot/lib
    $sudo cp   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2  /chroot/lib
    $sudo cp  lib/i386-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1 /chroot/lib
    $sudo cp /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /chroot/lib
```

su command

```
    $which su
    /bin/su 
    $sudo cp /bin/su /chroot/su
    $ldd /bin/su
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7737000)
            libpam.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0 (0xb770d000)
            libpam_misc.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpam_misc.so.0 (0xb7709000)
            libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb755a000)
            libaudit.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1 (0xb7535000)
            libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb7530000)
            /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7738000)

Copy this lib file to chroot lib directory

    $sudo cp /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0 /chroot/lib
    $sudo cp  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpam_misc.so.0 /chroot/lib
    $sudo cp /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6  /chroot/lib
    $sudo cp /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1 /chroot/lib
    $sudo cp /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 /chroot/lib
    $sudo cp /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /chroot/lib
```

Add some system configuration files and additional libraries to the chroot

```
    $cat /etc/passwd | grep acer > /chroot/etc/passwd
    $cat /etc/passwd | grep root >> /chroot/etc/passwd
    $cat /etc/group | grep acer > /chroot/etc/group
    $cat /etc/group | grep root >> /chroot/etc/group
    $cat /etc/shadow | grep acer > /chroot/etc/shadow
```

Copy nsswitch.conf file to /chroot

```
    $sudo cp /etc/nsswitch.conf /chroot/etc/nsswitch.conf
```

Inside the nsswitch it should looks like the follow

```
    passwd: files
    group: files
    shadow: files
    hosts: files
    networks: files
    protocols: files
    services: files
    ethers: files
    rpc: files
    netgroup: files
```

We copy the configuration files necessary for the PAM system to operate so that the authorization in the jail can work

```
    $sudo cp /etc/pam.d/common-account /chroot/etc/pam.d/
    $sudo cp /etc/pam.d/common-auth /chroot/etc/pam.d/
    $sudo cp /etc/pam.d/common-session /chroot/etc/pam.d/
    $sudo cp /etc/pam.d/su /chroot/etc/pam.d/
```

We add some additional libraries required by the PAM and the name service switch facilities

```
    $sudo cp /lib/libnss_files.so.2 /chroot/lib
    $sudo cp /lib/libnss_compat.so.2 /chroot/lib
    $sudo cp /lib/libnsl.so.1 /chroot/lib
    $sudo cp -fa /lib/security/ /chroot/lib
```

We need to create login.defs file in /chroot/etc/ directory.This file defines some setting for the login process

```
    $sudo vim /chroot/etc/login.defs
```

Add the following line in to the login.defs file

```
    SULOG_FILE /var/log/sulog
```

If we did not do this the su command would attempt to use the syslog utility,which is not available in the jail setup and the entire process would fail.

Create the script that will put our user in jail,whenever he login in to the system

Create file jailshell in /bin directory,outside the jail

```
    $sudo vim /bin/jailshell
```

Add the following script in to that file

```
    #!/bin/bash
    sudo chroot /chroot /bin/su acer
```

Make it executable

```
    $sudo chmod  +x  /bin/jailshell
```

To put script in action,we need to edit the /etc/passwd file (which is outside of the jail).

Change /bin/bash to /bin/jailshell in  user acer

```
    $sudo vim /etc/passwd
    acer:x:1003:1003:,,,:/home/acer:/bin/jailshell
```

Set user acer in jail's home directory

```
    $cd /home/acer
    $sudo cp -fa ./ /chroot/home/acer
```

The following could also be useful

```
    $sudo cp /etc/bash.bashrc /chroot/etc/  
    $sudo cp /etc/localtime /chroot/etc/
    $sudo cp /etc/services /chroot/etc/
    $sudo cp /etc/protocols /chroot/etc/
    $sudo cp /usr/bin/dircolors /chroot/usr/bin/
    $sudo cp /usr/bin/groups/ /chroot/usr/bin/
```

Everything done.Now test the login

```
    $su – acer
    password:xxxx
    [sudo]password for acer:xxxx
    acer@Snovabits:/$ ls
    bin dev etc home lib    usr var
```